# Downloading large result

Tags: java, micronaut

Is it possible to use the declarative client to download a large result by e.g. using an `InputStream`? I tried a client signature like

```
HttpResponse<InputStream> getQueryResult(String jobId, String resultId);
```

But it tries to download the whole body, which then leads to

```
io.micronaut.http.client.exceptions.ContentLengthExceededException: The received length exceeds the maximum content length
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens here is that your client requests a fully received (aggregated) HttpResponse, wrapping a byte array which is then converted into an InputStream. In order to get the response bytes without aggregation, you need to request one of the reactive types, such as a `org.reactivestreams.Publisher` (or a suitable subclass thereof) of `ByteBuffer`s. Then you need to process those.

Example:

```
Flowable<ByteBuffer<?>> getQueryResult(String jobId, String resultId);
```

You can then run `map`, `forEach`, `blockingForEach`, etc. on that `io.reactivex.Flowable` - BUT REMEMBER TO FREE THE BUFFERS, or you'll generate a lot of garbage, and get nasty log messages. Example (in Groovy):

```
Flowable<ByteBuffer<?>> responseFlowable = myClient.getQueryResult("job1", "foo")
int sum = 0
responseFlowable.blockingForEach { ByteBuffer byteBuffer ->
    sum += byteBuffer.toByteArray().count('!')
    ((ReferenceCounted)byteBuffer).release() // Let Netty do its thing!
}
```

(Obviously, blocking is bad for high throughput, but it's just an example)

I hope this helps.